# Getting multiple errors when trying to open a browser in kali linux on wsl2

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am still new to the whole wsl world, so i don't really what's going on here. Chromium was working 2 hours ago and now it stopped working. I've tried uninstalling and installing it again, but nothing changed. Also tried several other browsers: google-chrome, firefox, vivaldi, tor and even brave. I really need to be able to open a browser, so some help would be appreciated.

Trying xdg-open

```
[24518:24547:1025/132327.616565:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24518:24547:1025/132327.616713:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24518:24547:1025/132327.840235:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24518:24547:1025/132327.840290:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[24557:24557:1025/132327.860721:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[24518:24547:1025/132327.887854:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24518:24547:1025/132327.887897:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
```

Trying sensible-browser

```
[24651:24683:1025/132509.916104:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24651:24683:1025/132509.916298:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24651:24683:1025/132509.943653:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24651:24683:1025/132509.943695:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24651:24683:1025/132509.994811:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24651:24683:1025/132509.994878:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[24693:24693:1025/132510.073677:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[24782:24782:1025/132510.202711:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[24842:24842:1025/132510.337176:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[24866:24866:1025/132510.378456:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[24722:8:1025/132510.382270:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
```

Trying chromium

```
[24927:24956:1025/132531.588962:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24927:24956:1025/132531.589048:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24927:24956:1025/132531.603545:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24927:24956:1025/132531.603596:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24927:24956:1025/132531.626858:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24927:24956:1025/132531.626913:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[24967:24967:1025/132531.715027:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[24993:25007:1025/132531.718700:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
```

Trying firefox

```
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.jsm
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.sys.mjs
```

Some extra info:
So the only thing i did is downloading kali linux from the microsoft store. After that i could start kali with the 'kali' command in cmd.
[image: Kali from microsoft store]
My OS:

[image: OS info]

Output of 'wsl -l -v':

```
  NAME          STATE           VERSION
* kali-linux    Running         2
```

Output of 'wsl --status':

```
Default Distribution: kali-linux
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 23/09/2022
The Windows Subsystem for Linux kernel can be manually updated with 'wsl --update', but automatic updates cannot occur due to your system settings.
To receive automatic kernel updates, please enable the Windows Update setting: 'Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows'.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel.

Kernel version: 5.10.16
```

If i am not providing enough information, please tell me about it, so i can edit my question. Thanks in advance y'all

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks. I added the info u asked for in my question. I don't have an idea how i am running graphical apps in wsl. Could u tell me how i can find out? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trying i finally found a way to fix this problem. To be honest i still don't know what i am doing, but hey, i did fix it :).

So after a hours of researching i found this [site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl), which talks about GPU in Windows Subsystem for Linux and CUDA. Since my laptop uses nvidia graphics card, i clicked on Get Cuda Driver and selected the drivers compatibale with my graphics card ([here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/193884/en-us/)). After restarting my laptop, kali wouldn't work at all, and i got the following message:

```
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
```

Copy paste into google got me to this [website](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/please-enable-the-virtual-machine-platform-windows-feature-and-ensure-virtualization-is-enabled-in-the-bios/).
Restarted my laptop again, pressed F2 to get into BIOS and made sure that VT was enabled in the Advanced tab.
I went to the control panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Turn on Virtual Machine Platform (was disabled on my machine) and Windows Subssystem for Linux. Restarted my laptop again.

After that i still got the following error when starting chromium:

```
[625:656:1026/162226.083770:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[625:656:1026/162226.083873:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[625:654:1026/162226.086365:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[625:654:1026/162226.086402:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[625:654:1026/162226.095330:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[625:654:1026/162226.095371:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[625:654:1026/162226.114368:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[625:654:1026/162226.114411:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[625:705:1026/162226.155182:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[625:705:1026/162226.155223:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[625:705:1026/162226.155277:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[625:705:1026/162226.155312:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[625:705:1026/162226.155346:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[664:664:1026/162227.046227:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
```

But this time chromium popped up.
[image: Chromium finally working]
I don't know if the first part of the solution (where i downloaded the drivers) had to be done, but it did help me find the problem.